# Drupal Panels add edit links to node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-panels

I have change the default display of a node type to use panels but I don't seem to have the view, edit, version etc tabs. How do I add them to my panel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tabs are a part of the page elements group when inserting content into your panels. You can see the tabs in the right column at the bottom. If you add that to your panel then you will get the tabs on your node pages.
[image: panel view]

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the proper path to your views?

No need to add to panel.

Just give the path to your views and add filters/rows to display.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to make a view to output the node fields you need. And add 'edit link'
 there. Then use this view in the panel instead of the node.